# How do you get Gold Skulls in Quest Mode?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

I noticed in the archives section of Towerfall Ascension, there is a section for how many skulls you have collected and I noticed that there are golden skulls.  How do you achieve these?

Comment: Which game are you talking about here? Your question isn't about the PS4, its hardware, operating system or any system-unique feature so that is not the correct tag.

Comment: Towerfall Ascension

Comment: If you feel my answer is sufficient, could you accept it?

Answer (score 7):

Gold skulls are earned by completing hardcore mode without dying.